Split a .table.sql script into multiple files
I have generated a file with schema and data of a table. The file is huge, so I need to split it in several files, no editor can open it.
I have tried Ultra Edit but the files appeared truncated
I need to transport data by internet.

Split it when you generate it, not after.

Why do you need an editor to open it? Have you considered using the bcp utility to export the table's data into a native format file instead?

You need a better tool.  Get yourself a license for V The File Viewer.  This is an oldie-but-goody designed to open files like what you're encountering.  But it is a VIEWER.  Editors try to load the entire edited file into RAM, and that's your problem right now.  V loads "pages" of data instead of the whole file.
